# Program creates more threads than requested

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a parallel merge sort.

But I'm facing a problem here:

- I'm getting more threads than what given to the program which is `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`.

**CODE:**

```
            Thread tl, tr;

            tl = new Thread(new MergeSortRunner(left, threadCount - 1));
            tr = new Thread(new MergeSortRunner(right, threadCount - 1));
```

The data is being sorted yet the number of used threads doesn't correspond to `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`.

**OUTPUT:**

```
.
. 
. 
Thread-190
Thread-229
Thread-171
Thread-183
Thread-191
Thread-187
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 23, 23, 23, 24, 25, 29, 29, 30, 35, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 44, 46, 46, 47, 49, 49, 50, 51, 52, 52, 52, 54, 55, 58, 58, 59, 59, 60, 61, 61, 62, 62, 63, 64, 64, 64, 64, 65, 66, 66, 69, 70, 70, 72, 73, 73, 74, 74, 75, 75, 76, 78, 82, 84, 86, 87, 87, 88, 88, 91, 91, 93, 93, 94, 96, 96, 97, 99, 99, 99, 100, 100, 101, 103, 103, 103, 104, 105, 108, 109, 109, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 114, 117, 119, 120, 120, 120, 122, 125, 125, 127, 128, 129]
```

I'm totally aware of the existence of `Executor` and `Fork/join`. But as said, I'm trying to implement it using threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both left and right branch of the recursion get to use `(threadCount - 1)` threads, together they'll use twice that number: `(2*threadCount - 2)` threads.

The number of threads you give each branch should add up to the limit you are given. For example, for a 50-50 split across left and right use:

```
int threadsForBranches = threadCount - 1; // remove 1 to count current thread
tl = new Thread(new MergeSortRunner(left, threadsForBranches / 2));
tr = new Thread(new MergeSortRunner(right, threadsForBranches - threadsForBranches / 2));
```